# Django generates wrong number of forms in formset after initialization

Tags: django, django-forms

I have following declaration of Formset:

```
ModelAFormSet = generic_inlineformset_factory(
    ModelA,
    form=AddModelAForm,
    formset=BaseModelAFormset,
    min_num=1,
    extra=0)
```

and ModelA looks as follows:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

   content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
   model_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

When I'm initializing my formset following way:

```
init_list = []
for my_model in self.edit_parent.my_models.all():
   dictionary = { 
     'name': my_model.name,
     'description': my_model.description,
     'id': my_model.id}
   init_list.append(dictionary)

formset = ModelAFormSet(initial=init_list)
```

I am always generating only one record. No matter what the len(init_list) is. I've been trying to find explanation for this, but no luck.

**Additional info**
After removing `min_num` and `extra` from ModelAFormSet resulting in

```
ModelAFormSet = generic_inlineformset_factory(
    ModelA,
    form=AddModelAForm,
    formset=BaseModelAFormset)
```

Number of generated forms is sort of correct. I have 2 forms which I would expect wit data assigned to them and (that's incorrect part) one extra empty form. What's more when I completely remove `min_num` no form is generated.

Comment: `ModelAFormSet = generic_inlineformset_factory(ModelA,form=AddModelAForm,    formset=BaseModelAFormset,min_num=1, extra=0,validate_min=True)`  Here we set `min_num=1` .So it will work then add `validate_min =True` .Similarly  if we set `max_num=1`,then it validate must add `validate_max=True`.Just try this if you want this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `extra` argument should be equivalent to the number of forms you expect to see. There's no need to set `min_num` unless you want to validate the number of forms.

```
class MyView(generic.CreateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        init_list = [...]
        formset = generic_inlineformset_factory(
            ...
            extra=len(init_list),
        )
        context['formset'] = formset(
            self.request.POST or None,
            initial=init_list,
        )
        return context
```

Comment: But can I modify `extra` once factory has been initialized?

Comment: I can't think of any cases you'd need to. Basically you are telling the factory to create `n` blank forms. When you instantiate the formset using `initial` those blank forms are filled with data. You can add a blank form on the client side using JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, but if I'll use JS on the client side then what's the point of having `initial` or `extra` at all? Doint everything in backend seems like much cleaner option. As for the reason why - factory and instantiated formset are in two different files; same formset can be used to edit existing records (`extra` is known beforehand) or create new one (`extra` is unknown).

Comment: Yes, I agree it's cleaner in the backend. What I mean is I don't understand why you want to modify `extra`. Your factory should be defined in the same file as wherever you are generating the `init_list`.

Comment: @sebap123, you can actually modify extra from frontend. See the source html of the generated form. You'll see that there are some hidden inputs related to extra forms. You. need to change it's value and send along with other POST data.

Comment: @sha256 yes I know. E.g. django-dynamic-formset is using this concept. But that's again rather unclear and a bit hack-type solution.

Comment: @sebap123, this is definitely not a hack-type solution. If you want it to be dynamic, this is the way to go. you can always perform sanity check in the backend.

Comment: @sha256 I agree with you that when I want to be dynamic that's the way to go - 100% true. The question here is regarding setting initial info - so I don't need to be dynamic, because I know beforehand how many forms I need to have.